# Connecting to a database through a webservice

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services, asmx

Could someone please help me to connect to a database through a webservice in c#.

I currently have,

1. The webconfig with the connection string listed.
2. A dbml file, which is referencing 1 table in the database I wish to query.
3. The asmx file with all my methods. These are all currently functioning, but I now wish to   add some additional web methods to query the database.

Could someone please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. The webservice should be connecting to the database, and your consuming code should connect to the webservice. You do not connect to a database directly through a webservice.

Comment: Can't I write sql/linq into a web method that can then query the database and return the xml?

Comment: yes you can write sql/linq into a web method that returns XML. As you already have an asmx file containing web methods are you having a particular problem writing another 1?

Comment: My methods are fine and the web service is functional but now I want to query the database through the web service within the asmx file, and don't know how to make the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention you have a DBML file, I'm assuming your'e using Linq-to-SQL.  ScottGu has some great starter tutorials on using the technology.  Here is one of them:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx

Bottom line at the very basic level you're DBML has a bunch of code behind including the DataContext classes that you run your queries against, using something like:

```
DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1Datacontext();

var q = from table in dc.SomeTable
select table;
```

Again the link above has some really good examples of how to use Linq-to-SQL.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks. Though I do have to provide a connection string to the dc object. Is there any way around that?

Comment: If you open your DBML file and bring up the Properties pane, there should be a section called "Data" and below that "Connection".  You can specify a specific Connection String in here (vs. in code).  Or even better when you added the DBML it should have created an entry in your app.config/web.config in <connectionStrings> and that Connection property should already be something like "XYZConnectionString (Settings)", which means its pulling from your .config file.